# Prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \le -5 \iff 1 \le (2x + 3) / (x - 2) \le 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove what is in title; i.e.,

$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x \le -5 \iff 1 \le \frac{2x + 3}{x - 2} \le 2
$$

Here's what I have so far:

- ($\leftarrow$, Case 1: $x - 2 \ge 0$) I think this case is impossible
  $$x - 2 \le 2x + 3 \le 2x - 4 \tag{2nd inequality is impossible}$$
- ($\leftarrow$, Case 2: $x - 2 \lt 0$)
  $$ x - 2 \ge 2x + 3 \ge 2x - 4 \tag{by algebra}$$
  $$\iff x \le -5 \land 0 \ge -7 \tag{2nd inequality is trivial}$$

I get stumped with the forward direction, though:

- ($\rightarrow$)
  $$x \le -5$$
  $$\Rightarrow 2x \le -10 \tag{multiply by 2}$$
  $$\Rightarrow 2x + 3 \le -7 \tag{add 3}$$
  and also
  $$\Rightarrow x - 2 \le -7 \tag{sub. 2 from the hypothesis $x \le -5$}$$

Is it acceptable to "divide" these 2 inequalities? That is, it seems it would get me to the first inequality of the conclusion, which is
$$\frac{2x + 3}{x - 2} \ge 1$$
but I'm not sure if this is allowed, nor am I sure if the inequality gets flipped because both $x - 2$ and $-7$ are negative.

Finally, I'm not at all sure how to get the 2nd part of the inequality in the conclusion.

Comment: @Nik That quotient is equal to 1, not -1.

Comment: dividing inequalities, in general, is not correct. Instead, you want to show that $$x\le-5 \implies \frac{2x+3}{x-2}\le2 \Leftrightarrow 2x-3\ge 2x-4\Leftrightarrow -3\ge-4$$ which is obviously true. Now try to show the other inequality similarly.

Comment: Oops! My bad. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Hint: restate the problem as $2-x\ge7\iff 0\le\frac{7}{2-x}\le1$.

Comment: @J.G. that is very clever! So I would work forward from $2 - x \ge 7$ to reach the conclusion? How were you able to think of that? Is it mostly experience?

Comment: I thought of it by adding a constant to $\frac{2x+3}{x-2}$ to make the numerator constant. I then sought to exploit the fact that, for $c>0$, $y\ge c\iff0<\frac1y\le\frac1c$; it saves you worrying about reciprocals of negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Being if $\:a\le \:u\le \:b\:\mathrm{then}\:a\le \:u\quad \mathrm{and}\quad \:u\le \:b$ we have

$$1\le \frac{2x+3}{x-2}\iff \frac{x+5}{x-2}\ge 0, \quad S_1: x\le \:-5\quad \mathrm{or}\quad \:x>2$$

But $$ \frac{2x+3}{x-2}\le \:2\iff \frac{7}{x-2}\le 0, \quad S_2: x<2$$

Merge overlapping the intervals $S_1$ and $ S_2$ we have: $S=\{x\le -5\}$. Then $$ 1 \le \frac{2x + 3}{x - 2} \le 2$$ is true $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x \le -5 $.

Comment: Wouldn't the union $S_1 \cup S_2 = \{x | x \in \mathbb{R} \land x \neq 2\}$? Or $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{2\}$? In any case, that seems to only be the $\leftarrow$ direction if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @ChrisWatson You are out of the way sorry. You have to do the union of intervals since there are two assigned inequalities.